# force.com ide has to reinstall on every startup of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

I installed Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) and Force.com IDE, lightning support and debugger. However everytime I close eclipse I'm prompted to reinstall these three components as if I never installed them at all.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: We'll probably need to see some logs to figure out what's going on. Have you taken a look at the logs yet?

Comment: using this: Help | Show Force.com IDE Log? There's nothing interesting there except messages from my programming work.. Are there other logs to look at? Eclipse is still open.. I also noticed that if I go into Help | Installation Details | Installation History there is only history from today's installation.